# How do I get information from an iframe with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, iframe, beautifulsoup

I need to get the average score from an iframe of an ecommerce link: `https://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-1218117849-par-farol-polo-hatch-sedan-2003-2004-2005-2006-cromada-_JM#position=1&type=item&tracking_id=d57fba01-b043-49ca-9be5-7b026c275bd4`

The iframe can be accessed by clicking in the stars bellow the title.

When I inspect the element I find this:

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="iframe-modal " data-modal:url="/noindex/catalog/reviews/MLB1218117849?noIndex=true&amp;itemId=MLB1218117849&amp;modal=true&amp;modalWidth=840&amp;modalHeight=400&amp;access=stars" data-modal:dinamic="true" data-modal:width="840" data-modal:height="400" data-modal:frameless="1" data-modal:style="new">
```

In which case I need the `'data-modal:url='`, that is `'/noindex/catalog/reviews/MLB1218117849?noIndex=true&amp;itemId=MLB1218117849&amp;modal=true&amp;modalWidth=840&amp;modalHeight=400&amp;access=stars'` to, then, be able to get the '4.7' average stars information.

I've tried a bunch of options I've seen here, but I couldn't even get the link. The closest I got is probably:

```
eval_url = (soup.
                 find('a', {'rel':'nofollow', 
                            'class':'iframe_modal ',
                            'data-modal:url':True}).get('data-modal:url').text)
```

Still, it's not working. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To get the `4.7` average stars information, you can select element with `class="review-summary-average"`.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-1218117849-par-farol-polo-hatch-sedan-2003-2004-2005-2006-cromada-_JM#position=1&type=item&tracking_id=d57fba01-b043-49ca-9be5-7b026c275bd4'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('.review-summary-average').text)
```

Prints:

```
4.7
```